# What does the angle bracket syntax mean in a function call?

Tags: c++, syntax

What does this syntax mean?

```
ForExample<Something>();
```

Can someone explain with a few examples how and what for it can be used?

Comment: `ForExpample` would be a function, templated on type `Something` and is being called with no arguments.

Comment: Please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: is it possible to pass another function as a parameter?

Comment: @CoryKramer It could also be a class-template, and this statement creates a temporary object.

Comment: Without any kind of context (most specifically the definition or at least declaration of `ForExample`) it's impossible to say anything certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code could be a call of the template function or instantiation of temporary class object.
For example, function is defined as:

```
template <typename T>
void ForExample(){
   // Do something
}
```

This function can be called as:

```
ForExample<int>();
```

In your case type Something can be any type (int, double, string, float ...)

Or we can define template class:

```
template <typename T>
class ForExample {
 // something
};
```

Temporary object can be created as:

```
ForExample<int>();
```

Comment: Why do I need to specify the data type in <> when calling the function?

Comment: As the name implies "template" is not the real function definition. Think about template like pattern which is used to create real function. You have to replace type T with real type (int, double, string...), type T is generic type and could be anything you want. And that's the reason you have to specify <some type> when calling function. This process is called instantiation.